# save data from edittext with "enter" as different item

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I don't know how to say it so I just give an axample, this is how I input:
[image]

can I save it in array or listview as different item instead of one item when I press save button? I want to save it like this;

```
resep                          resep
=====                          =====
item1                          item1
-----                          item2
item2     instead of this ->   item3
-----                          -----
item3                          =====
=====
```

its purpose is to facilitate user to input several items at once with ease, at first I made it with `EditText` and add button to save it in `ListView`, then save everything in `ListView` with the save button, but they say it did't simple enough, and they told me to do it as my example above, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string on `\n` so you can get each row as a separate String, rather than having them all stored in one string variable.

Try something like this:

```
String rawData = yourEditText.getText().toString();
String[] rows = rawData.split("\n");
for(String row : rows){
    //saveItem(row);
}
```